# SVG Inconsistencies Between Browsers

Tags: html, css, svg, cross-browser

I am creating a site with SVGs like this. I have a few problems with the live site though. First, the text inside the SVG is not using the font for some reason. If I post the code here or on codepen, it works, but not on the live site. Another issue is that the text positioning is not consistent in Chrome or Microsoft Edge. I have included the HTML and JS code for reference.

HTML

```
<svg viewBox="0 40 100 40">
    <defs><path id="textPath"/></defs>
    <g id="testGroupC2" >
      <style type="text/css">

          @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:thin');
          text{
            font-size: 4pt;
              fill: #ffffff;
              text-anchor: middle;
              font-family: 'Raleway';
              z-index: 2;
          }

      </style>
      <path id="testPath2"/>
      <text>
          <textpath xlink:href="#textPath" startOffset="50%" >
              <tspan x="0" dy="-5.5">Home</tspan>
          </textpath>
      </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

JS

```
// JavaScript Document

const rad = Math.PI / 180;

let cx = 50, cy = 100, R = 50, r = 35, A = 40 , a = 5, o=4;
// o for offset
testGroupC2.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", `rotate(${-90 -(A / 2) - a} ${cx} ${cy})`)


// control points for the quadratic Bézier
let px1 = cx + R * Math.cos(0);
let py1 = cy + R * Math.sin(0);
let px2 = cx + R * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let py2 = cy + R * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);
let px3 = cx + r * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let py3 = cy + r * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);
let px4 = cx + r * Math.cos(0);
let py4 = cy + r * Math.sin(0);

// points used to draw the shape
let x11 = cx + (R-o) * Math.cos(0);
let y11 = cy + (R-o) * Math.sin(0);

let x1 = cx + R * Math.cos(a*rad);
let y1 = cy + R * Math.sin(a*rad);

let x2 = cx + R * Math.cos((a + A)*rad);
let y2 = cy + R * Math.sin((a + A)*rad);

let x21 = cx + (R-o) * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let y21 = cy + (R-o) * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);

let x31 = cx + (r+o) * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let y31 = cy + (r+o) * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);

let x3 = cx + r * Math.cos((a + A)*rad);
let y3 = cy + r * Math.sin((a + A)*rad);

let x4 = cx + r * Math.cos(a*rad);
let y4 = cy + r * Math.sin(a*rad);

let x41 = cx + (r+o) * Math.cos(0);
let y41 = cy + (r+o) * Math.sin(0);

/*
No rounded corners
let d = `M${x1},${y1} A${R},${R},0 0,1 ${x2},${y2}
         L${x3},${y3} A${r},${r},0 0,0 ${x4},${y4}
         L${x1},${y1}Z`;*/

/*
Beveled corners
let d = `M${x1},${y1} 
         A${R},${R},0 0,1 ${x2},${y2}
         L${x21},${y21} 
         L${x31},${y31}
         L${x3},${y3}
         A${r},${r},0 0,0 ${x4},${y4}
         L${x41},${y41}
         L${x11},${y11}
         L${x1},${y1}Z`;*/

// Rounded corners with quadratic Bézier curves
    d = `M${x1},${y1} 
         A${R},${R},0 0,1 ${x2},${y2}
         Q${px2},${py2} ${x21},${y21} 
         L${x31},${y31}
         Q${px3},${py3} ${x3},${y3}
         A${r},${r},0 0,0 ${x4},${y4}
         Q${px4},${py4} ${x41},${y41}
         L${x11},${y11}
         Q${px1},${py1} ${x1},${y1}Z`;

testPath2.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);


/* based on the 2nd A-curve of the testPath,
   but last point and starting point switched,
   as well as the sweep-flag of the curve */

    dtext = `M${x4},${y4}
         A${r},${r},0 0,1 ${x3},${y3}`;

textPath.setAttributeNS(null,"d",dtext);
```

Comment: Your JAvascript variable `testGroupC2` is never defined.

Comment: Yes it is, check again.

Comment: The code you posted above only has `testGroupC2.setAttributeNS(..)`, but never initializes the variable (it would probably need to be `const testGroupC2 = document.getElementById('testGroupC2')`). Same btw is true for `textPath` and `textPath2` near the end of the script. Maybe there is a part of your code you failed to post? Only wanted to get sure.

Comment: The code runs fine, it draws the necessary SVG shape and positions the text in Firefox and Safari. Those lines are referring to IDs in the HTML.

Comment: I need help, not nitpicking or criticism on code standards and whatnot. Only comment if you have a solution to my problem above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the font, if I go to the Google fonts website, it [tells me](https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Raleway:100) to use

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100');
```

Does this make a difference?

For font positioning, you should be aware that the `pt` unit you use for the font size is device-dependent and may be interpreted differently by different software. It is always preferable to use `px` values, especially since you set a `viewBox` on the `<svg>` element. This way, the font size is guaranteed to always remain the same size in relation to that viewbox.

Now `4pt` is a relatively small value that comes with the risk that browsers apply optimizations to improve the shape rendering - effectively repositioning glyphs. (For small sizes I am often tempted to call them buggy.) There are two strategies to tackle this:

1. Set the CSS property [`text-rendering: geometricPrecision`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#TextRenderingProperty) to disable repositioning.
2. Scale all numbers used: Choose a scaled-up viewBox, a scaled-up font size and scaled-up path data, such that the internal proportions are preserved. The final size the `<svg>` is rendered at is goverened by its `width` and `height` presentation attributes, anyway.